# Place ads after second paragraph of the posts in a specific category

Tags: wordpress

I want to place ads after second paragraph of the posts located under a specific category. For this I am trying to run the following piece of codes but it is not working. Kindly help me out.

```
//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.
$catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
foreach ($catarray as $cat) {
$catid = $cat->term_id;

if ($catid == 124);

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );  
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

$ad_code = '<div>Insert Ad code here</div>';

if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
}
}  
return $content;
}


// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
$closing_p = '</p>';
$paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
    $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
}

if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
    $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
}
 }

return implode( '', $paragraphs );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for it

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ak_the_content_filter', 10, 1);
function ak_the_content_filter($content)
{
  $catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  foreach ($catarray as $cat) {
   $catid = $cat->term_id;

   if ($catid != 124) { return $content; }
  else{
    $parags = explode('</p>', $content);
    $parags[1] .= '<br>'.do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE HERE]');// add whatever you want after first paragraph

    $content_new = '';

    foreach ($parags as $parag) {
        $content_new .= $parag;
    }

    return $content_new;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much Kumawat; you are a savior.

Comment: Thank you @user31225, If possible please upvote and mark it right answer.